# Gradient Method of solving $\mathbf{Ax}=\mathbf{y}$

Tags: matrices

The problem; solve a linear system of equation:

$$\mathbf{Ax}=\mathbf{y}\tag1$$

can be recast as; Find $\mathbf{x}$ to minimise the 'error residual', a column vector, $\mathbf{r}$, defined as a function of $\mathbf{x}$ by:

$$\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Ax}\tag2$$

My notes say to find the square of the norm of the residual, $||\mathbf{r}||^2$, and equates it as follows.

$$||\mathbf{r}||^2=(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Ax})^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Ax})\tag3$$

Could someone explain how to get from 2 to 3 please?  Thanks.

Comment: Think dot product!

Comment: Note that $y$ is a vector, and $Ax$ is a vector, so $y-Ax$ is a vector, and the vector dot product can equivalently be written as $v\cdot v = v^Tv$.

Comment: $\|x\|^2 = x^T x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$||r||^2=r\cdot r=r^Tr$$ They are just re-writing it as a dot product.